# Implementing reference to another entry in the same table in Hibernate

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa

I have the following configuration in Hibernate:

```
@Entity
class Foo{

    @Id
    private Long id;

    Foo parent;

    Foo left_child;

    Foo right_child;

 }
```

Do I need to create special annotations because I am referring to elements that live in the same table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that each row can be referenced by multiple rows, you should use the `@ManyToOne` annotation. You can optionally define the join column name using the `@JoinColumn` annotation, e.g.:

```java
@ManyToOne @JoinColumn(name="parent_id")
Foo parent;

@ManyToOne @JoinColumn(name="left_child_id")
Foo left_child;

@ManyToOne @JoinColumn(name="right_child_id")
Foo right_child;
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need "special" annotations to map self-joined fields. Use normal unidirectional associations with join columns (e.g. `ManyToOne` for `parent`).